# CRM2016 SP1 Remove marketing list members stuck

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a static marketing list for contacts. When I press the button "manage members" and want to remove members using other marketing lists, I can start the removel.

My main marketing list contains 2300 contacts. The marketing list for removel contains 100 members.

But the removel does never finish. It just stucks on the popup (internet explorer) "please wait" or (Firefox) "Data is beeing prepared. Please wait..."

Does anyone have experienc with this?

Answer (score 0):

The main marketing list was locked. Thats why it did not procced.
Unfortunatly there is no warning telling you that.

Tank you anyways.